# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'transID'

Tags: python, class, error-handling, bioinformatics

Here is a class I defined in python3.

```
class BlastHit():
    '''
    instance attributes:
        entry: one line from blast output file
        transID: transcript ID
        SPID: SwissProt ID (without the version number)
        ID: identity
        MM: mismatch

    methods:
        constructor
        __repr__ 
        goodMatchCheck: 
            method that returns whether the hit is a really good match (e.g. >95 identity)
    '''
    def __init__(self, entry):
        self.entry = entry
        splited_line = entry.rstrip().split("\t")

        # Find transcript ID (transID)
        qseqid = splited_line[0]
        self.transID = qseqid.split("|")[0]

        # Find SwissProt ID (SPID)
        sseqid = splited_line[1]
        sp = sseqid.split("|")[3]
        self.SPID = sp.split(".")[0]

        # Find identity (ID)
        self.ID = splited_line[2]

        # Find mismatch (MM)
        self.MM = splited_line[4]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"BlastHit('{self.entry}')"

    def goodMatchCheck(self):
        return float(self.MM) >= 95.0

    def list_results(self):
        results = list()
        results += self.transID
        return results
```

And I tried to run the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    BlastHit.list_results("c0_g1_i1|m.1 gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO  100.00  372 0   0   1   372 1   372 0.0   754")
```

However, the system kept giving me the same error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'transID'

Whoever have an idea, please share with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BlastHit.list_results("c0_g1_i1|m.1 gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO  100.00  372 0   0   1   372 1   372 0.0   754")
```

You are calling the `list_result` as if it were a static method. So the string that you are passing is being bound to `self`.

You need to create an instance and use that instead:

```
bh = BlastHit("c0_g1_i1|m.1 gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO  100.00  372 0   0   1   372 1   372 0.0   754")
bh.list_results()
```